# Python pandas dataframe splitting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this kind of dataFrame which I would like to split into seperate dataframes:

```
A B C Mark
3 5 6 T
4 5 2 T
3 4 5 B
5 6 7 B
3 4 5 T
2 5 2 T
```

For instance the table above should be split into three pandas dataframes. First dataframe the two rows with Mark "T" as one dataframe, the second dataframe the next two rows with Mark "B" and the third dataframe the last two rows with Mark "T".

df1

```
A B C Mark
3 5 6 T
4 5 2 T
```

df2

```
 A B C Mark
   3 4 5 B
   5 6 7 B
```

df3

```
A B C Mark
3 4 5 T
2 5 2 T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary as below:

```
frames = {}
for i, grp in df.groupby(df.Mark.ne(df.Mark.shift()).cumsum()):
    frames.update([('df_'+str(i),grp)])

{'df_1':    A  B  C Mark
 0  3  5  6    T
 1  4  5  2    T, 'df_2':    A  B  C Mark
 2  3  4  5    B
 3  5  6  7    B, 'df_3':    A  B  C Mark
 4  3  4  5    T
 5  2  5  2    T}
```

You can then test by printing all the dfs as :

```
print(frames['df_1'])

   A  B  C Mark
0  3  5  6    T
1  4  5  2    T
```

Comment: Thank you! I liked your answer. Here I can name each dictionary differently etc. 'df_T_to_B'. Actually that was what I wanted as well.

Comment: Pleasure @Abbos :)

Answer (score 1):

Create dictionary of DataFrames with consecutive counter by `shift` and `cumsum` with convert groupby object to tuples and then to dictionary:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['Mark'].ne(df['Mark'].shift()).cumsum())))
print (dfs)
{1:    A  B  C Mark
0  3  5  6    T
1  4  5  2    T, 2:    A  B  C Mark
2  3  4  5    B
3  5  6  7    B, 3:    A  B  C Mark
4  3  4  5    T
5  2  5  2    T}
```

Select each DataFrame:

```
print (dfs[1])
print (dfs[2])
print (dfs[3])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is really nice and compact script. And it is exactly what I wanted, however there are some advanced stuff which makes it a bit hard to understand.

Comment: @Abbos - Ok, only ask me, I try explain more.

Answer (score 0):

Another way around wrapping this into `np.array_split` for the given Post:
However, `np.array_split` returns a list of DataFrames hence you can list then down and even loop through the list.

### Outcome:

```
>>> np.array_split(df, 3)
[   A  B  C Mark
0  3  5  6    T
1  4  5  2    T,    A  B  C Mark
2  3  4  5    B
3  5  6  7    B,    A  B  C Mark
4  3  4  5    T
5  2  5  2    T]
```

Listing them as an individual dfs:

```
>>> df[0]
   A  B  C Mark
0  3  5  6    T
1  4  5  2    T

>>> df[1]
   A  B  C Mark
2  3  4  5    B
3  5  6  7    B

>>> df[2]
   A  B  C Mark
4  3  4  5    T
5  2  5  2    T
```

Or you can assign them names:

```
df1 = df[0]
df2 = df[1]
df2 = df[2]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your suggested script works well in this particular case as it is in example. What if I would have hundreds of rows and don't know exactly how often mark changes.